# How to create and call custom function at Theme's function.php for a plugin

Tags: wordpress, function

I need to create a custom function for plugin `wp-estore` . Function should be added on `function.php` of Theme and should be called at plugin.

Comment: define the function in plugin file so it will automatically called in your active theme file.

Comment: @AkshayShah I want to create a function in function.php of theme. My need to call it from plugin.

Comment: you can override the function from the plugin to theme but you can not do the reverse. You are saying to add the function in theme and you wish to call that in your plugin. Am i right ?

Comment: @AkshayShah Yes I need to call theme'f function in my plugin.

Comment: Is it not possible using Hook or any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are loaded before the theme so the function hasn't been defined at the time you're calling it. Execute your code on a hook such as init instead.

```
function wpse_my_plugin_init() {
myPreviouslyUndefinedThemeFunction();
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_my_plugin_init' );
```